# Ajax call to invoke controller's method

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My code:

```
 $(function () {
    $("input#Submit1").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Home/GetPort',
            method: 'GET'                
        }); 
       alert("test");          
    });
 });
```

I have added alert to just check click event.
It does not work if i remove alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the alert message out of the click event:

```
 $(function () {
    $("input#Submit1").click(function () {
      alert("test");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Home/GetPort',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(status){
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function(x){
                alert(x);
            }

        });           
    });
});
```

Add the error function to check what error you are getting and add the success function to check whether is working fine or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function myCustomFunction() {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "saveGroupMaster.controller",

    success: function(response){
      alert('success');
    },
    error: function(e){
    alert('error');        
  }
});

}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Can you please try this:**

```
$(document.ready(function() {
    $("input#Submit1").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Home/GetPort',
            method: 'GET'                
        });           
    });
    });
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I have already tried this. It does not work but thanks for your time.